# Laptop air flow is too weak on heavy CPU load (3D gaming)?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I don't really know how to diagnose this before proceeding with a right decision to solve this problem. I know for sure that the air-flow should be much stronger at that high load of CPU. I can hear the sound fine (loud enough) but the air-flow is not much strong as expected (checked by placing my palm right in front of the air-flow exit). As before once I played one 3D game, the maximum temperature is just about 80 Celsius degree and at that high load the air-flow can blast your palm (placed around the air-flow exit) **clearly** BUT now I don't have that feeling. Also the maximum temperature now can reach 90 Celsius degree (so it's fairly logical to the weak air-flow). The air-flow sound is just like being clogged by some fluff.

I've just have my laptop (of course regard of its fan) **cleaned** but it's just like what I described above.

Could you give me some suggestions about what could be wrong with it? Replacing fan? upgrading the BIOS? something wrong with the fan controller? It's so ridiculous that the fan itself is just simple, its main parts are that the coils distributed correctly and there should be no way for it to function incorrectly (being weaken but not just stopped?). The most possible reason may involve the fan controller but still I cannot explain the air-flow sound (like being clogged by some fluff, cannot exit normally). I may have to buy a new laptop just because of its failed cooling system, its dedicated GPU becomes useless when it cannot run for a long time due to high-temperature issue. So bored, please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there also a filter on the air input that needs cleaning?

Comment: 90°C is still an acceptable temperature for Intel’s mobile CPUs. It throttle after that, though.

Comment: @DavidPostill the filter has been cleaned fine as well.

Comment: @DanielB the problem is not which level the CPU can allow (mine is about 105 degree Celsius) but still it's abnormal and there should be some problem here, without fixing that issue, my laptop cannot endure long (I'm sure that even after cleaned OK like I've just done, it will become hot again after 1 month playing 3D games with heavy load of both CPU and GPU.

Comment: is it possible that the fan somehow rotates in the inverse direction? I cannot imagine how the air-flow could be so weak, the exit heat can be felt but there is not any clear flowing of hot air.

Comment: “is it possible that the fan somehow rotates in the inverse direction?” – no, absolutely not. However, the bearing could be damaged. You can always try and check the fan RPM using hardware monitoring software.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for your response, I think the RPM is fairly normal, it variates around 3000-5000. This is really hard to diagnose, I'm not so sure if this is a problem of OS. My laptop was bought in 2012 and it has drivers  supported for Windows 7, Windows 8. Now I'm using Windows 10, almost drivers are not usable (such as the Fn key does not work because of lacking drivers ...). It's even more terrible if it is the problem of the CPU itself (I mean it can emit more heat than it did before). Next time I may try replacing the fan and hope it will be better.